# How to use GitLab "personal access tokens" for programmatic access to the repo?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a big project where we had lots of issues with mismatching properties being chosen while building different modules and so I wrote us a little Groovy utility the pulls misc. pom.xml files from the repository and - before deploying - checks for these properties to match.

The utility is working fine but now I am having an issue with authentication.
For testing I always just logged into the repo using the browser and then copied the session cookie from the HTTP headers and passed it to the utility. The utility used this argument to set the Cookie in the HTTP(S) requests and that worked OK - at least for testing.

Since these cookies always only last an hour or so I would rather use a git "personal access token" for the utility's authentication since these can last longer (up to a year).

So I create a read-only token and copied it out but now - what do I do with that token?
Do I add this as ?-argument to the URL? Do I pass it in an HTTP header? In which one? Is it to be used as the password fraction for a Basic Authentication header? Or how is such a PAT to be used when access the repo programmatically (i.e. not via the browser or via the git cmd-line)?

Hope I could make myself clear...

Comment: Is there something that keeps you from using SSH?

Comment: Yes - there is only HTTPS access to that repo. And these tokens are the suggested (and soon the only) way to authenticate. And the second point is that using SSH is more complicated than just opening a URL-connection in Java/Groovy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record and in case someone else stumbles over this thread:
the access token is simply appended to the URL like so: `<URL>?private_token=<your_token>`.

And that only works when accessing the GitLab **REST-API**, not via the browser/UI calls.

We are using GitLab to store our code. To download a file one simply needs to construct the URL like so:

```
String url ="https://<git-server>/api/v4/projects/<repo-nr>/repository/files/<path-to-requested-file>/raw?ref=<branch-name>&private_token=<your-token>"
URLConnection conn = url.toURL().openConnection();
String content = conn.content.text
... handle your file's content here ...
```

Note: `<path-to-requested-file>` must be given with all slashes replaced with `%2F`

Comment: Can you give more of an example? This could be really useful to someone.

Comment: I added a snippet from my code showing how I get hold of a file's content via GitLab's API using a simple GET request.

Comment: This seems applicable only to GitLab. But the original question never mentioned GitLab at all.

Comment: My bad - I edited the title accordingly.

Comment: Added a `gitlab` tag too.